# Show consolidated CSS for a page

Tags: css, debugging

I'm looking at a web page with a dozen CSS links.  Is there any browser or tool that can automatically consolidate those, ideally without me having to open and copy the contents of each one, so I can see what the resulting styles look like?

I know I can see the computed style for a particular tag using element inspectors, but I want to also be able to see styles that may not be used on any particular page.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.csstrashman.com/

It will consolidate CSS and keep only the part in it used by the page you asked for. It shoud do what you are looking for.

Comment: That is pretty cool!  And if it worked (which it didn't on my first test case) it would almost do what I was looking for.  What I really want is the consolidated style _including_ styles that are not in use on the page in question.

Answer (score 0):

Most web debuggers have this. Certainly, with Firebug (for Firefox) there is a CSS button on the main menu that you can use to examine and modify all the stylesheets that are loaded. For Safari on the Mac, use the menu Develop | Show Page Resources. This lets you do the same thing. Chrome and IE also have this.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something: All of these only let you look at one CSS file at a time.  There is no consolidation, unless you ask for the styles applicable to an element on the page that you can point to.